# Android - ellipse to the left textView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three elements like that:

ELEMENT1 - ELEMENT3

The second element is "-"

By default with ellipse Android will truncate the ELEMENT3, but I want to truncate ELEMENT1. Is there a way to accomplish that?

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO"
                android:textColor="@color/text_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=" - "
                android:textColor="@color/text_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO CIAO"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:textColor="@color/important_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: The second element and the third elements must be aligned to the left!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the layout weight attribute to control the "importance" of each element in a LinearLayout.  See here for more information: [Linear Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

I've taken your xml layout below and edited it a bit to produce the result which I think you are looking for.  Note that TextView1 has layout weight 1, whilst TextView2 and TextView3 have layout weight 0.  What this does is force the LinearLayout to assign space to TextView2 and TextView3 first and then assign whatever space is left over to TextView1.  Therefore TextView1 is the element that will be ellipsized first.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="element1element1element1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text=" - " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="element3element3element3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've added the part that the "-" should be left aligned and not right aligned. With layout_weight I have this problem :(

Comment: Just set the layout_width of the LinearLayout to wrap_content.  I've edited the example above.